# Disabled categories still show products in search

Tags: category, products

I have a lot of disabled categories that are having a lot of products. Whenever I search for something a lot of those products still show up in the search.

Now I know that I can go manually to each product and set the Visibility to "Not Visible Individually" but this is a very tedious job. I first have to see what products that disabled category has. Then I have to copy it's SKU, then go to the products search, paste that SKU, edit the product, change the visibility, click save... and repeat.

I have at least 500 products in those disabled categories.

Is it possible to automatically look for the disabled categories and NOT show up the products that those categories have?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the search functionality to do this task but that won't be recommended. You can select those products from admin panel change their `visibility` to `Catalog` only.

If you really want to this and for one time only then write a sql query and execute that.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int as eav 
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  SET eav.value='2'
where ea.attribute_code = 'status' and eav.entity_id IN 
 (select product_id from catalog_category_product
where category_id IN  
(SELECT distinct(e.entity_id)
FROM catalog_category_entity e
JOIN catalog_category_entity_int eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  where attribute_code='is_active' and value=0));
```

**Query Description**

This query is selecting categories which all have status inactive

```
SELECT distinct(e.entity_id)
FROM catalog_category_entity e
JOIN catalog_category_entity_int eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  where attribute_code='is_active' and value=0;
```

Then select products from `catalog_category_product` table which all are associated with these categories.

```
SELECT product_id FROM catalog_category_product
 WHERE category_id IN  
(SELECT distinct(e.entity_id)
FROM catalog_category_entity e
JOIN catalog_category_entity_int eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  WHERE attribute_code='is_active' AND value=0)
```

Then Set value for attribute which you want to change. If you want to disable the product then use status attribute or just to change the visibility you can select visibility attribute and add respective value.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int as eav 
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
  SET eav.value='0'
where ea.attribute_code = 'status' and eav.entity_id
```

Comment: Problem is that I can't select all those products at once. I need to find all the disabled categories, then I need to find all the products of those disabled categories, and only then I can set them to Catalog only. Any idea how to do this? Thank You

Comment: You can do this from mysql but the point is, if the product is associated with another category which is active ?
Are you sure with the scenario then you can have some joins in your sql and you will be able to get the id's which need to be updated.

Comment: I don't think any of the products are part of multiple categories. Anyone have any idea on how to do the SQL line? Thank You

Comment: You can take reference from this
https://gist.github.com/ticean/735798
You can customize this or I'll write for you later. Its midnight here.
 m out for sleep now.

Comment: I havn't SQL in something like 7 years. I would love if it would be possible for you to help me. I'm sure this would be useful for some other people.

Comment: I have added the SQL query in answer. Take database backup before executing any direct query on database.

Comment: Thank You. I will let you know how it worked when I get home.

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Comment: I just tried it out. I had about 1500 rows affected... from 2200 products that I have in the database. From what I searched in the admin panel, the products still appear as "Catalog, Search" but the problematic products appeared to be "Out of Stock". I cleared the cache & I did the reindex and... they seem to be gone. So... in a way... it worked? I'm still confused.

Comment: 1500 tables or rows ? :)

Comment: Rows. I edited my post. I pressed enter to write a new line and it automatically added the message.

Comment: I written query for disabling the product, so they will be in Catalog, Search state, You can modify the attribute from status to visibility and change the value to 1 from 0 and you will find those products status changed.

Comment: Add me on skype: Pixiez (I also added you on facebook for a fast chat. Chose where you want to have a fast chat, if you want to have a fast chat). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would write an sql query selecting the products in the category ( catalog_category_products), match their id by a select from the catalog_product_entity table and setting their visibility to 0.